# Can't get .focus() to focus on an input with an id in Chrome, Safari, and FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, focus

I am having issues with a code I am using to check email validity before sending it off to a database. I have a javascript code that checks the email in the following way:

1. See if the first email is a valid email address
2. See if the two email fields match

Here is the relevant parts of the form:

```
<form action="URLGOESHERE" method="post" name="someName" onSubmit="return validation();" id="formId"> 
    <section class="sectionHeader">
        <h2>Contact Information</h2>
        <span class="important">*Required Fields</span>
    </section>
    <section id="contactInfo">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Contact Information</legend>
        <div id="contact">
            <div class="inputGroupSameLine">
                 <label for="name" class="left"><span class="important">*</span>First Name:</label>
                 <input type="text" name="firstName" class="imp" size="20" maxlength="25" placeholder="John">
            </div>
            <div class="inputGroupSameLine">
                  <label for="name" class="left"><span class="important">*</span>Last Name:</label>         
                  <input type="text" name="lastName" class="imp" size="20" maxlength="25" placeholder="Smith">
            </div>
            <div class="inputGroupSL">
                <span class="left"><label for="org">Company/Group Name:</label></span>
                <input type="text" name="org" size="30" maxlength="50" placeholder="Auburn University">
            </div>
            <div class="inputGroupSameLine">
                <span class="left"><label for="email"><span class="important">*</span>Email:</label></span>
                <input name='email' id='email' class="imp" type='text' size='45' maxlength='45' placeholder="youremail@example.com" />
            </div>
            <div class="inputGroupSameLine">
                <span class="left"><label for="email2"><span class="important">*</span>Re-type Email:</label></span>
                <input name='email2' id='email2' class="imp" type='text' size='45' maxlength='45' placeholder="youremail@example.com"/>
            </div>
            <div id="phoneGroup">
                <span class="left"><span class="important">*</span>Phone #:</span>
                <input name='phone' type='text' class="imp" id="phone" size='12' maxlength='20' placeholder="xxx-xxx-xxxx"  />
            </div>
            <div id="extGroup">
                <span class="left">Ext:</span>
                <input name='ext' type='text' id="ext" size='12' maxlength='6' placeholder="xxxx"  />
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</section>
```

And here is my code that runs onSubmit:

```
var reEMail=/^\w[\w\-\.]+\@\w[\w\-]+(\.[\w\-]+)+$/;

function validation() {
    if (!checkImportant()) {
        alert("Please enter information in all fields marked important.");
        return false;
    }
    if (!checkAttendees())
        return false;
    if (!checkEmail($('#email'),$('#email2')))
        return false;
    return true;
}

function checkImportant()   {
    important = document.getElementsByClassName('imp');
    for (i=0; i < important.length; i++) {
        if($(important[i]).val() == "") {
            $(important[i]).focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function checkAttendees() {
    total = 0 + Number($('#numAttend').val());
    parts = 0 + Number($('#8').val()) + 0 + Number($('#12').val()) + 0 + Number($('#16').val()) + 0 + Number($('#19').val()) + 0 + Number($('#26').val()) + 0 + Number($('#26').val()) + 0 + Number($('#55').val());
    count = 0;
    if (total != (parts)) {
        alert('Please check to ensure you have entered the correct number of participants.');
        count++;
        if (count%2 == 0) {
            $('#numAttend').focus();
            return false;   
        }
        else {
            $('#8').focus();
            return false;   
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function checkEmail(email,email2)   {
    if (goodEMail2(email)) {      
        if (email.val() != email2.val()) {
          alert("Please check to make sure your email address is correct in both fields!");
          email2.focus();
          return false;
        } 
        else return true;
    }
    else {
      alert("Please input a valid email address");
      setTimeout(function(){
    $('#email').focus();
    }, 100);
      email.select();
      return false;
    } 
    return false;
}

function goodEMail2(field) {
   return _checkIt2(reEMail, field);
}

function _checkIt2(re, field){
  if (!re.test(field.val())) {
      field.select();
      field.focus();
      return false;
  }
  else return true;
}
```

As you can see in my main if else statement of my checkEmail function I am having to use setTimeout to delay the focusing on the email field. If I take out the setTimeout, the page *will not* focus on the element. However, if I take out the setTimeout and change the specified element to the second email field, it works.

The only exception to this is in IE10 (to my testing in FF, Chrome, Safari, and IE10).

I don't really want to use this work around and I don't understand why I need to. Can anyone give me some ideas or answers?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Can't seem to get my hack to work now. I'm not sure what it was doing before... so now focus() doesn't work at all on that particular element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing:

```
function checkImportant()   {
    important = document.getElementsByClassName('imp');
    for (i=0; i < important.length; i++) {
        if($(important[i]).val() == "") {
            $(important[i]).focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

to:

```
function checkImportant()   {
    important = document.getElementsByClassName('imp');
    for (i=0; i < important.length; i++) {
        if(important[i].value == "") { // drop the jQuery reference, not needed
            important[i].focus();      // drop the jQuery reference, not needed
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

worked for me in Chrome

Comment: Thanks for that one - but thats not the area I'm having trouble with - it's the email that I can't seem to focus on.

Comment: "You don't have permission to access /adventure/schedule.php on this server."

Comment: sorry, forgot to change permissions. Should be good to go now

Comment: yup... leaving email blank, it gives a pop-up and then focuses on the email field.

Comment: That's triggering the checkImportant function. If you fill in all the fields with an * and then put garbage text in for both emails, it alerts but doesn't focus.

Comment: That's because it's not validating the type of data in the field, but just whether or not there IS data in the field.

Comment: That's true of the checkImportant function, which is not the function that is giving me trouble. The function that is the issue here is the one which checks that the first email field contains a valid email (checked using goodEmail2() first, and then in turn, _checkIt2(), which checks the value in the email field against a regular expression. Then if this returns false, it returns false until the main else loop, where it should select and focus on the email field.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zyVFF/2/   Still seems to be working. I had to comment out checkAttendees() as it's not a part of your supplied code.

Comment: Switching the values in the email fields gets you to the case I am testing. I see that in the fiddle it is working, but on my actual form, when you click submit it fails to scroll you back up to the targeted field. Any thoughts?

Comment: Well, from a design perspective, I would shorten the form a lot (kill a lot of white space, widen the form a bit, etc), there's already too much scrolling happening for the user. You could add a window.scroll(0,0); to your check failure, that would scroll the window back to the top.

Comment: I think I misunderstood focus(). I thought it was supposed to center the browser to the field it was focused on!